# $n^{th}$ roots of $-x$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Okay this question can be interpreted as an extension to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448993/nth-roots-of-negative-numbers), however I need to have the validity of my claim checked.

Let $x \in \Bbb R, z \in \Bbb C, n \in \Bbb N$

The solution to the equation
$$z^n = -x$$
is as follows:

Let $\omega \in \Bbb C$ such that $ \omega^n = -1$, Then

$$\omega^nz^n=(\omega z)^n=x.$$

We can define $\omega$ as the $n^{th}$ root solution to $-1$ as follows where $k, j \in \Bbb Z^+$ and $\,j, k<n$

$$\omega = \exp\left(\frac{2\pi k i }n\right)\exp\left(\frac{\pi i} n\right)$$

$$\implies \omega z = x^{1/n}$$then

$$z = \frac {x^{1/x}}{ \exp\left({2\pi k i }n^{-1}\right)\exp\left({\pi i} n^{-1}\right)}$$

We can define the $n^{th}$ roots of $x$ as

$$x^{1/n}=p_n\left(x\right)\exp\left(\frac{2\pi j i }n\right)$$

where $p_n(x)$ is the principle $n^{th}$ root of $x$ (as defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/322487/87191)). Finally

$$\begin{align}
z&= p_n(x)\frac {\exp\left(2\pi j i n^{-1}\right)}{  \exp\left({2\pi k i }n^{-1}\right)\exp\left({\pi i} n^{-1}\right)}\\
z&=p_n(x)\,\,{\exp\left(i2\pi \left(j-k-2^{-1}\right)n^{-1}\right)}
\end{align}$$

It can be stated that there are $n$ solutions using $j, k$ as selectors of these roots. If $j = k$ then it gives the same value for all values of $j$ and $k$ respectively.

Comment: By the functional equation of the exponential function, the quotient in the last equation reduces to $\exp (2\pi(j-k)in^{-1})$, and two pairs $(j_1,k_1), (j_2,k_2)$ give the same value if the remainder of the differences modulo $n$ is the same, so you have only $n$ distinct solutions (unless $z = 0$, when there is only one).

Comment: What is the principle $n^{th}$ root of $x$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for the observation will change acordingly

Comment: @MakotoKato the square roots of 1 are 1 and -1. The principle square root is 1.

Comment: @Alizter What is the principle square root of $x = -2$?

Comment: @MakotoKato The square roots of $-2$ are $\sqrt 2 i$ and $- \sqrt 2 i$. The principle one is the first

Comment: @Alizter Sorry. I should have asked what the principle 3rd root of -2 is. I hope you explain in general what the principle $n$-th root of $x$.

Comment: For $x \in \Bbb R^+$ the principle nth root is the nth root such that $z \in \Bbb R^+$. Also $x \in \Bbb R^- \implies z \in \Bbb R^-$

Comment: @Alizter Unfortunately, that description doesn't work. If $x\in\mathbb R^-$ and $n$ is even, then *none* of the $n$th roots of $x$ are in $\mathbb R^-$. Negative numbers are different from positive numbers, so you can't always take a statement about $\mathbb R^+$ and transplant it into $\mathbb R^-$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a closer look at this part:

> We can define $\omega$ as the $n^{th}$ root solution to $-1$ as follows where $k, j \in \Bbb Z^+$ and $\,j, k<n$
>
> $$\omega = \exp\left(\frac{\pi k i }n\right)$$

What do you get if you calculate $\omega^n$?

Comment: Yes I see the problem. If $k = 0$ then this doesn't hold true.

Comment: @Alizter Right! In fact, for any even $k$ it doesn't hold true.

Comment: @ChrisCutler I have fixed it

Comment: @Alizter There's still a problem. Try $n=4$ and a few different values for $k$.

Comment: @ChrisCutler How about now?

Comment: @Alizter Much better! Equivalently, you could write $k+\frac12$ or $k-\frac12$. Or you could bring a factor of $(-1)^n$ outside of the exponential. There are many ways to express the same thing.

Comment: Would this statement still hold true if $k$ and $j$ were the same variable?

Comment: @Alizter If $k=j$ then your expression still gives one of the $n$th roots of $-x$, but it doesn't give the other $n-1$ roots. If you're looking for a way to simplify the expression by eliminating one of the variables, you could just set $j=0$ or $k=0$. I think this is what Daniel Fischer was hinting at in his comment.